# NotificationManager.cancel() is not working

Tags: android, android-notifications, notificationmanager, android-statusbar

I want to delete a notification which is located on my status bar. I used Notification Manager.cancel() but it didn't work. I used cancelAll() too with the same result.

My code is:

```
public class NotificationListenerService extends android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService {

...

@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
nManager.cancel(sbn.getId());
nManager.cancel(sbn.getTag(), sbn.getID());
nManager.cancelAll(); 
}
```

I found more answers here on SO but none solved my issue. The sbn object is right, I print in my log all its data.

It's possible to delete an exiting notification located on the status bar with Android API < 20? (so without using cancelNotification())

Comment: why people downvoted my question without explain nothing? Is it a dumb question? Ok, but explain why it is. It's the only way to learn.

Answer (score 0):

- With API >= 21, you can try use the method [cancelNotification (String key)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html#cancelNotification(java.lang.String))
- With API < 21, you can try use the method [cancelNotification (String pkg, String tag, int id)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html#cancelNotification(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int))

Comment: can you attach the code when you show notification item?

Comment: Log.i("Tag", sbn.getTag());
Log.i("ID", "" + sbn.getId());

result is:

I/Tag: ONE_TO_ONE:100000283080218:100007345449145
I/ID: 10000

Comment: you can try the method [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html#cancelNotification(java.lang.String)) `cancelNotification`

Comment: cancelNotification is working but it can be used only with min API 21. No clue for cancel()?

Comment: with API < 21, you can try with function cancelNotification (String pkg, 
                String tag, 
                int id)

Comment: this is link  : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html#cancelNotification(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,int)

Comment: of course, but it running on API < 21.make sure the input data is correct.

Comment: the data is what I wrote up, It should be correct but I don't know why it is not working.